# highWaterMark does not work as expected on Readable Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, stream, node-streams

Im practicing some code to understand node streams better, but I have stepped on some doubts

In my understanding, highWaterMark defines the buffer size of the streams, given the example bellow:

```
let count = 1;
const readable: Readable = new Readable({
    highWaterMark: 10,
    encoding:'utf-8',
    read(size?: number) {
        console.log(count++);
        console.log(this.push('1'));
        
    }
});

readable.on('readable',()=>{
    console.log('read result => ' + readable.read());
    count = 1;
});
```

Printing the result:

```
1
true
2
true
3
true
4
true
5
true
6
true
7
true
8
true
9
true
10
false
11
false
read result => 11111111111
```

Which makes sense, since the max. buffer size is 10 bytes, it keeps pushing data until it reaches its threshold, emiting then the 'readable event'

But if the stream is on flowing mode, the highWaterMark limits nothing:

```
let count = 1;

const readable: Readable = new Readable({
    highWaterMark: 10,
    encoding:'utf-8',
    read(size?: number) {
        console.log(count++);
        console.log(this.push('1'));
        
    }
});

readable.on('data',(chunk:any)=>{
    console.log('read result => ' + chunk);
    count = 1;
});
```

Result:

```
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
1
true
read result => 1
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't the stream wait to fills up the buffer and send the data?
Some things still are blurry

Comment: 1. Think of _paused_ mode as PULL and _flow_ mode as PUSH. In PULL the data is buffered until full and then pauses until you tell it to _resume_. In PUSH the buffer is constantly flushed to the eventhandler. 2. You can't expect _paused_ and _flow_ modes to work identically. You _can_ make them work that way. For instance, in your _flow_ mode example, just after `count=1;`, put `readable.pause()` - this places the steam back in  _paused_ mode.  The inverse can be seen in the `readable` event handler by adding `readable.resume()` - it continues on forever.

Comment: so basically the highWaterMark it's just for pause mode

Comment: I think that's what you'll find if you supply more data than your threshold size - it just  doesn't have an impact.

Comment: Can you answer my question? I'll vote as the best